# Why does prophet produce much tighter prediction intervals than ETS?

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval, exponential-smoothing, prophet

I'm currently working on a forecast problem, where narrow prediction intervals are preferred.

When I look at the prediction intervals of ETS and prophet forecasts, *I'm surprised that the prophet algorithm produces so much tighter intervals, especially for longer term forecasts*.

- What is the reason behind this? (Is it because prophet is an additive model without autoregressive dynamics?)
- What would be an appropriate way to decide, which prediction intveral is correct? (I have only about 5 years of data, which may not be sufficient to compute interval error metrics on past data.)

Edit: just stumbled across this link, which is probably revelant: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/871#issuecomment-468832774

Here is an example showcasing the difference between the two algorithms:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)
library(fable.prophet)

airpass_tsbl <- as_tsibble(AirPassengers)

airpass_tsbl %>% 
  model(ets = ETS(value),
        prophet = prophet(value ~ season("year", 4, type = "multiplicative"))) %>% 
  forecast() %>% 
  autoplot(airpass_tsbl)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You probably mean *prediction intervals* a.k.a. *forecast intervals* rather than *confidence intervals*. There is a difference.

Comment: Prophet by default just finds the MAP for the parameters so I think if you use the MCMC samples you can get to a more robust prediction interval.  Also, I can be wrong about this, but I do not think Prophet takes into consideration the length of the forecast when deriving the interval just the variance around its parameters.  And I do not know the ETS package in R but if it is additive by default then for this series it would have a larger interval anyway.

Comment: I just rechecked: For this dataset the ETS function also selects a multiplicative model `ETS(M,Ad,M)`).

Comment: Narrower prediction intervals are only preferred if they aren't *wrong*. You should use proper scoring to determine which model produces better intervals. You say you have 5 years, but what's the frequency of the data?

Comment: It's monthly aggregation I'm currently most interested in.